# How set UILabel maximum length?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

My label shows one field of web service.I want to display 10 characters of my label.My code is not working.

In didEndElement code :

```
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"StationName"] ) {
      StationName.text = retornoSOAP;
      returnSOAP = nil;
      tReturn = NO;    
  }
```

This code is working.It displays StationName field to StationName label

Where is my mistake here ?

```
  - (void)viewDidUnload {
         *NSString *temp =@"                                  ";

            if ([temp length] > 10) {
              NSRange range = [temp rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){0, 10}];
              temp = [temp substringWithRange:range];
            }

             StationName.text= temp;
    }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this no need to take range all those thing simply use this substringToIndex method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { // not in viewDidUnload
    StationName.text=temp;
    if([StationName.text length]>10){
            StationName.text=[StationName.text substringToIndex:10];
        }

}
```

Comment: It is not working in my code.Label is empty when I use this

Comment: @Mehmet Akyel:befor eusing this method you can set the value for StationName.text=@"your text";...

Comment: @Mehmet Akyel:check my answer now.

Comment: @Mehmet Akyel:from where you are getting label text and where you want to assign the text?

Comment: from web service.if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"StationName"] ) {
      StationName.text = retornoSOAP;
      returnSOAP = nil;
      tReturn = NO;    
  }

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason why your code does not work is that you are invoking it in the wrong place: `viewDidUnload` is a rather unlikely candidate for being the right spot, because it's usually called too late to influence anything visible on screen. In addition, you start your `temp` with a long chain of spaces, so in the end you get exactly ten spaces in the label.

Shortening the label in the code that sets it should work much better:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"StationName"] ) {
    *NSString *temp = retornoSOAP;
    if ([temp length] > 10) {
        NSRange range = [temp rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){0, 10}];
        temp = [temp substringWithRange:range];
    }
    StationName.text= temp;
    returnSOAP = nil;
    tReturn = NO;    
}
```

Comment: When I use this code my label equal empty after loading fields.

Comment: @MehmetAkyel That's strange. Are you sure this code gets executed? Check with a debugger or add an `NSLog` before assigning `temp` to `StationName.text`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Because you want to write your code in `viewDidLoad` but now you have written in `viewDidUnload`. And you can get string with 10 character like this:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    if ([temp length] >10) 
    {
          temp = [temp substringToIndex:10];
    }

    StationName.text= temp;
}
```